# Installing Ubuntu Server on a cloud

Tags: server, cloud

I want to know if there is any way to install a version of Ubuntu Server 16.04 64 bit on a cloud server. I do not have physical access to the machine. How would I be able to do it over SSH or in some other way.

Comment: That depends on the "cloud" service provider. Some offer prepared images that can be set up via web interfaces or API calls, some offer rescue systems which would allow ssh access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question could have multiple answers depending on how you're using 'cloud'?

Typically cloud would be considered a logical server delivered through virtualization.  Your cloud provider allows you to select an image to boot, which the image could be Ubuntu.  So there isn't really an 'installation' but you still end up with an Ubuntu ready server.

If you mean a physical server colocated at a remote location, the best way I've found to get Ubuntu installed is, having your remote hands put the CD into the drive and install Ubuntu over IPMI.  I've done it several times, if all goes well, the disc should only have to put inserted once.

Comment: Thanks my host provider gave me a per-made image to boot up.